# javascript, how to get html to persist after button click

Tags: javascript, html

Every time i click my HTML button the values are filled in for a brief flash and then disappear. want my variables to stay after the button is clicked. I I have tried putting the .innerHTML outside of the button click and altering just the variables in the js function. not sure what to do here. thanks.

HTML:

```
 < button id="evaluteScoreButton">Evaluate Scores</button >
```

js:

```
document.getElementById("evaluteScoreButton").onclick = function evaluateGrades() {
window.document.getElementById('dsumm').innerHTML = arrayAverage(discussionArray());
window.document.getElementById('tsumm').innerHTML = arrayAverage(testArray());
window.document.getElementById('asumm').innerHTML = arrayAverage(assignmentArray());
var totalAverage = findTotalAverage();
window.document.getElementById('totalAverage').innerHTML = totalAverage;
window.document.getElementById('letterAverage').innerHTML = (findLetterGrade(totalAverage));
```

};

Comment: When I simplify it (stubbing the functions I don't have), it seems to behave just fine. Can you provide more of the code? Here's the fiddle I worked with: http://jsfiddle.net/RdPtE/1/

Comment: Do any of the above array functions clear any values?

Answer (score 1):

Change the button type

Instead of

```
<button id="evaluateScoreButton">Evaluate Scores</button>
```

Try

```
<input type="button" id="evaluateScoreButton">Evaluate Scores</input>
```

The reasoning behind this is that I think the `<button>` element is a **Submit** button which causes the html form to be posted. Using an `<input>` should avoid this